# Is it possible to reverse the layout of the icCube pivot table widget?

Tags: olap, iccube, iccube-reporting

The current icCube pivot table widget shows the children below the parent.
When you click on a parent, the children will be displayed just below that specific parent.

Finance users are used to see a different layout: children above the parent that add up to the parent.

Is is possible to allow a reversal display (option: parents below children = YES). In this situation:
- a user clicks on a parent in a **row** and the children are displayed **above** the parent
- a user clicks on a parent in a **column** and the children are displayed **left** of the parent

Enclosed an example.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it's currently not possible. Strange, do you know of other tools that work like this ?

There is a workaround if you can live without drilldown and collapse features. In MDX there is an function that allows for showing the hierarchy as you describe, [Hierarchize](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Hierarchize.php) with the POST flag.

```
 Hierarchize( [Accounts].members, POST )
```

You'll have to disable collapse and navigation in the pivot table widget (Hide Icons to true + Navigation to None)

Comment: This is a good work-around for now. But it would really be a benefit if this functionality can be included.